# What the difference between -pool & -updates on SLES11-SPx

Tags: repository, suse, sles, data

I recently downloaded the updates for SLES11-SP3. The directory lists the following:

- SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool

  - .repodata
  - repodata
  - rpm
- SLE11-SDK-SP3-Updates

  - .old.repodata
  - repodata
  - rpm
  - .mirror
- SLES11-SP3-Pool

  - .repodata
  - repodata
  - rpm
- SLES11-SP3-Updates

  - .old.repodata
  - repodata
  - rpm
  - .mirror

What is the difference between the -pool & -updates directories?

Additionally, I was asked to update my SLES11-SP3 (non-SLERT) systems. Do I simply just add the "updates" directory to the repo in Yast or do I need to add both the -pool & the -updates?

(am I breaking any rules with the additional question in this forum?)

Comment: Some hints here (maybe) http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Suse/Upgrades_and_patching/service_packs.shtml#Procedure_of_upgrading_from_SLES_11_SP2_to_SLES_11_SP3_without_using_DVD .... Ref. https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=SLES11-SP3 -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-Pool** repositories are with GA packages ( packages on release disk) , can be set to no-refresh via zypper -> `zypper mr -R repo-name`

**-Updates** are repositories containing released updates, so every released patch/update for product is in this repository. This repositories must be set to refresh and are mandatory for `zypper patch` and `zypper up`

Both types of repository are needed, without Pool isn't possible install package which hasn't update. And Updates is self explanatory:)

Comment: I didn't think anyways was ever going to answer this. Thank you for your knowledge.